# JavaScript Date to Delphi TDateTime

Tags: javascript, delphi

I need to send via AJAX a date for a delphi server that accept the date in float format and set a `TDateTime` property.

Eg.

```
var
   date: TDateTime;
begin
   date := StrToFloat(Request.QueryFields.Values['date']);
end;
```

Delphi TDateTime start from 30/12/1989, i have tested with:

```
var
   date: TDateTime;
begin
   date := StrToFloat('0');
   ShowMessage( DateTimeToStr(date) ); // show: 30/12/1899
end;
```

JavaScript Date start from unix epoch, i have tested with:

```
console.log(new Date(0)); // Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100
```

a simple conversion seem subtract the difference, but doesn't works, eg.:

```
// javascipt
var delphiTime = (new Date("07-24-2019") - new Date("12-30-1899")) / 1000;
console.log(delphiTime ); // 3773084400


// delphi
ShowMessage( DateTimeToStr(3773084400) ); // show 00/00/00
```

the strange fact, on delphi, `Now` is 43670.654378:

```
ShowMessage( FloatToStr(Now) ); // 43670.654378
```

In delphi 0 is 1899 and 43670 is 2019...

How works the date format in Delphi and how convert a unix date to delphi date with math?

Side note: i can't modify the server, i need to solve the issue client side with javascript

**UPDATE:**

In Delphi the float value = 1 would be 31.12.1899, 2 = 01.01.1900 and so on. Each unit seem a day.

```
function jsDateToDelphiDate(date){
  const seconds = (new Date(date).getTime() - new Date("12-30-1899").getTime()) / 1000;
  const days = seconds / 60 / 60 / 24;
  return days;
}

console.log(jsDateToDelphiDate(new Date("07-24-2019 16:00:00"))); // 43670.625
```

`43670.625` on delphi is `23/07/2019 15:00`.

**Why i lose 1 hour?**

Comment: It doesn't work because of the concept of leap years. Every 4 years there's an extra day in February. So you can't just simply do math on dates, not that easily anyway.

Comment: @JerryDodge right! I had forgotten February :(

Comment: @JerryDodge The OP is losing 1 **hour**, not 1 **day**, so leap years is not a factor here. Since both Unix time and Delphi time are represented as simple offsets from given epochs, and neither one cares about how many days are in each month of a given year, simple math will work just fine to convert one to the other. Even Delphi's own `UnixToDateTime()` and `DateTimeToUnix()` functions take that into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How works the date format in Delphi

This is fully documented on [Embarcadero's DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com):

[System.TDateTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.TDateTime)

> The `TDateTime` class inherits a val data member--declared as a double--that holds the date-time value. **The integral part of a `TDateTime` value is the number of days that have passed since December 30, 1899. The fractional part of a `TDateTime` value is the time of day**.
>
> ...
>
> The following table displays examples of `TDateTime` values and their corresponding dates and times:
>
> ```
> Value     Description  
> 0         December 30, 1899; 12:00 A.M.  
> 2.75      January 1, 1900; 6:00 P.M.  
> -1.25     December 29, 1899; 6:00 A.M.  
> 35065     January 1, 1996; 12:00 A.M.
> ```

> how convert a unix date to delphi date with math?
>
> Side note: i can't modify the server, i need to solve the issue client side with javascript

A Unix date/time is represented as the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC.  Delphi has a `UnixDateDelta` constant in the `SysUtils` unit which is defined as `25569`, the number of days from December 31 1899 to January 1 1970.  So, a `TDateTime` value of `25569.0` exactly represents January 1 1970 00:00:00 (UTC vs local is up to you to decide when creating a `TDateTime`).  You can then add seconds to that value to get the final `TDateTime` value for any Unix date/time.

In a `TDateTime`, you can add whole days to the integral portion (ie, `Unix + 1 day = 25569.0 + 1 = 25570.0`), but adding seconds within a day is slightly more work, as seconds are not represented as-is in `TDateTime`, as you can see in the table above.  `0.25` is 6:00 AM (21600 seconds after midnight) and `0.75` is 6:00 PM (64800 seconds after midnight).  So seconds are represented in `TDateTime` as a fraction with 86400 (the number of seconds in a day) as the denominator.

A JavaScript `Date` object is represented as the number of milliseconds since midnight on January 1 1970.  You can divide a `Date` value by 1000 to get whole seconds, and divide that value by 86400 to get whole days and fractional seconds, which you can then add to `25569.0` to produce a `TDateTime` value.

```js
function jsDateToDelphiDate(dateToConvert){
  const UnixDateDelta = 25569.0;
  const SecsPerDay = 86400;
  const MSecsPerSec = 1000;
  var UnixSeconds = dateToConvert.getTime() / MSecsPerSec; // 1563984000
  var SecsToAdd = UnixSeconds / SecsPerDay; // 18101.666666666668
  return UnixDateDelta + SecsToAdd;
}

// don't forget to force UTC, or else the Date value
// will be skewed by the local timezone offset...
console.log(jsDateToDelphiDate(new Date("2019-07-24T16:00:00Z"))); // 43670.66666666667
console.log(jsDateToDelphiDate(new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 6, 24, 16, 0, 0)))); // 43670.66666666667
```

Delphi has a [`UnixToDateTime()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.UnixToDateTime) function in the `DateUtils` unit which performs this calculation for you.  So, if you can change your AJAX code to pass a Unix timestamp as-is to Delphi, you can let Delphi calculate a suitable `TDateTime`.

Note, in this example, the resulting `TDateTime` value is in UTC.  After transmitting the value via AJAX to Delphi, if your Delphi code needs a `TDateTime` in local time, that is a simple calculation to adjust the `TDateTime` based on the local machine's timezone offset in minutes, which you can get using platform APIs, such as [`GetTimeZoneInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-gettimezoneinformation) on Windows, etc.  Delphi has an [`IncMinute()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.IncMinute) function in the `DateUtils` unit that you can use for that adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

In JS, `valueOf` Date is in milliseconds. If you want to convert it to days, simply divide it by 24*60*60*1000.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the return value of `new Date().valueOf()` to Delphi TDateTime you can use this function:

```
function jsDateToDelphiDate(millis: int64): TDateTime;
begin
  var UnixSeconds: Integer := Round(millis / MSecsPerSec);
  Result := UnixToDateTime(UnixSeconds, False);
end;
```